# Problems in running Polymer Starter Kit on windows 8

Tags: node.js, windows-8, installation, npm, polymer-starter-kit

**Can anyone please tell me the proper requirement setup to run polymer starter kit on Windows 8.**
I am trying to run polymer starter kit on windows 8.

**First error during npm install**

> node version required 0.12.x instead of 4.2.2 ---------- I fixed that

**Than second error during npm install**

> Python required < 3.0, so I got python 2.7.10 ---------- I fixed that

**now during npm install, It is giving error of .NET Framework**

[image]

Comment: even I am facing the same issue did u manage any luck?
Did you downgrade node to 0.12? and share how you resolved the python issue?

Comment: Python and node issues are resolved. Whole problem is now with **bower-sync** in windows environment. You need to have **visual studio 2013** to  run bower-sync on Windows8